# Prove the Identity: $\cosh(-x) = \cosh(x)$

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

I am trying to prove this identity in my Calculus 1 class. Here is what I've got so far:

$\cosh(-x) = \cosh(x)$

$\cosh(-x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{-x} + e^{-{(-x)}})$

$\cosh(-x)=  \frac{1}{2}(e^{-x} + e^x)$

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: This looks right to me. I might change the structure of the proof, i.e., compute $\cosh(-x)$ and simplify it to $\cosh(x)$, but the idea is certainly correct.

Comment: Just commute the two exponentials.  And your done...

Comment: Awesome. I see now. Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.

$\cosh(-x)=  \frac{1}{2}(e^{-x} + e^x)  =  \frac{1}{2}(e^x + e^{-x} )$  (commutative property)

And the RHS is the definition of $\cosh(x)$